# Reducing JSON with jq

Tags: unix, jq

I have a JSON array of Objects:

```
[{key1: value},{key2:value}, ...]
```

I would like to reduce these into the following structure:

```
{key1: value, key2: value, ...}
```

Is this possible to do with [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)?

I was trying:

```
cat myjson.json | jq '.[] | {(.key): value}'
```

This doesn't quite work as it iterates over each datum rather than reducing it to one Object.

Comment: Does `cat myjson.json | jq '.[]'` output each object on a separate line? If so, you can then pipe this to something else (eg `sed`): `cat myjson.json | jq '.[]' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/}\n{/, /g'`

Comment: @turtle While looking over old questions I noticed this has been here for a while.  Perhaps consider marking an answer Accepted if it met your needs?

Answer (score 9):

Note that jq has a builtin function called 'add' that the same thing that the first answer suggests, so you ought to be able to write:

```
jq add myjson.json
```

Answer (score 4):

To expand on the other two answers a bit, you can "add" two objects together like this:

```
.[0] + .[1]

=> { "key1": "value", "key2": "value" }
```

You can use the generic `reduce` function to repeatedly apply a function between the first two items of a list, then between that result and the next item, and so on:

```
reduce .[] as $item ({}; . + $item)
```

We start with `{}`, add `.[0]`, then add `.[1]` etc.

Finally, as a convenience, jq has an `add` function which is essentially an alias for exactly this function, so you can write the whole thing as:

```
add
```

Or, as a complete command line:

```
jq add myjson.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will work:

```
cat myjson.json | jq 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; . + $item)'
```

It takes each item in the array, and adds it to the sum of all the previous items.